# Get end-to-end path of nodes with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find a cypher query that will get me an end-to-end path in a variable. I do not want every path segment as a new row.
Allow me to explain.

My data set is mostly millions of `Actions` with a `Next` relation to the next actions. 
What I've tried is the following query `MATCH x=(:Action)-[:NEXT*]->(:Action)`.
This gives the correct result in the graph view. However, the rows result is not what I want.

[image: required result]
Let's say this is my data set. With the above query I get back the following result: `0->1, 1->2, 2->3, 0->1->2, 1->2->3, ...` (so every possible path segment that fulfils the query requirements)
What I want is just the e2e path, so `0->1->2->3`.
For this dataset, it doesn't really matter. The real dataset however, contains much, much longer & much much more disconnected paths.
Even with a tiny dataset, this query takes a lot of time and returns way to much. 
Every next action added to a link will exponentially increases the amount of rows returned, and the query is terribly slow because of it.

So the question, how do I get only these e2e results?
The link lengths are variable, and so are the start & end nodes. These links are normally much longer, but they are filtered earlier in the query, so I can't just do something like check the one with no next relation to it/from it.

The reason why I need this is because I'm continuing on with this variable, I'm not just returning it.

**UPDATE:**

A more accurate version of what would be in the database.
[image: Data set]

Now I can filter on a day range, on a start location, or on an end location.
For example with the following query

```
// Get the days between the specified start&end
MATCH x=(a:Day{Date:'2019-02-23'})-[:NEXT*0..]->(b:Day{Date:'2019-02-26'})
WITH [n IN NODES(x) | Id(n)] as dayIds
MATCH (startDay:Day)<-[:ON]-(startAction:Item)
MATCH (endDay:Day)<-[:ON]-(endA:Item)
WHERE Id(startDay) IN dayIds AND Id(endDay) IN dayIds
// Filter on America as end
MATCH (endAction)-[:IN]->(toNode:Place)
WHERE Id(toNode) IN [44] //Id of America
MATCH result=(startAction)-[:NEXT*]->(endAction)
RETURN result
```

So I'm filtering both start & end action to be in the specified range.
Then I filter the end action on being performed in America.
After then doing `MATCH result=(startAction)-[:NEXT*]->(endAction)`
I get the following result.

[image: result]

In the graph view mode this is correct. However the result I'm returning to my .net application is the following.

[image: result view]

This is way too much. Again, for this dataset it isn't a big issue, but I'm talking big data here. Millions of records will be the result after filtering.
The problem is that my result has every pathsegment by itself in the result, and I just want the e2e paths as 1 result row.

Comment: does a "start" node just not have an inbound `-[:NEXT]->` and likewise does an `end` node just not have an outbound `-[:NEXT]->`?

Comment: @DaveBennett this is not guaranteed. As mentioned, the path in the screenshot is already filtered. It could be that a start node still has an inbound `Next`, but the action from which the `Next` originated is no longer in the filtered list.

Comment: So how do you determine what is a start node and what is an end node?

The essence of your problem is that you are literally matching every `(:Action)-[:NEXT*]->(:Action)` segment in your database and returning every . You need to narrow down what you are looking through.

Comment: That is exactly my problem, which is why I came here for a solution.
To determine what is a start node, I could check if the inbound next is from an action not in the list of possible nodes, but I can't find a way to make that happen.

Comment: What actions are allowed and not allowed? How do you know what and end node is?

Comment: Actions have many links to other nodes. Allowed actions are based on those other links. For example, one such link is to a day node. So the query could say only actions that have a day between a certain range. I implemented these filter by using matches on the startAction & endAction. Then I do `(startAction) - [:NEXT*] - >(endAction). But these start and end action can possibly be multiple nodes (even within the same chain)

Comment: Are you using the same filtering for your start and end nodes (are they in the same set) or are there different conditions for each? Can you supply a Cypher snippet that we can work off of?

Comment: Start and end nodes have different filtering. I'll update the question tomorrow morning with a better example, and with the snippet. Thanks!

Comment: Update is live.